# What would be reliable way to get PHP script return value from iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

To avoid using all that `FormData` in my simple *pseudo* AJAX form, I simply have a hidden iframe and I send the form into it:

```
<iframe name="frame" id="frame" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

I assign a onload callback to it when `<form>` is sent:

```
function formSubmit(form) {
   validateFields(form);
   document.getElementById("frame").onload = applyReturnData;
}
```

However, I have failed with all methods of harvesting the data out of the `<iframe>` DOM objects.
What I wanted to do was something like this:

```
 //In the callback, this reffers to the iframe object
 var data = this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
```

However, it offten messes up with the jsou data that script returns.

The PHP script that is being loaded in iframe returns json:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
die(json_encode($some_data));
?>
```

So, what would be the most reliable way of getting the `JSON` out of the IFRAME?

Comment: I would verify that the `die` function in PHP is causing a 200 HTTP status code to be returned with your response. If I remember correctly, the `die` function returns a 500 Server Error HTTP status, which means the `onload` callback in JavaScript is not getting called. Only 200 and 201 HTTP status codes for the IFRAME response should trigger the `onload` event handler in JavaScript. You might need to attach an `onerror` event handler to the IFRAME.

Comment: No, the onload is getting called. And I had never obtained error 500 upon `die()` call. Nothing like that is in [the documentation](http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) either. How did you happen to believe this?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done PHP development. Also, just wondering where the problem resides. If the "onload" handler is being called, are you getting a JavaScript error? Have you verified that the body of the HTTP request sent to the IFRAME is valid JSON? Can you give an example of the "messed up JSON"? I'm starting to think the problem lies with using the BODY element to store the JSON. If there are HTML tags in it, the browser might be trying to parse that as HTML. Maybe stuff the JSON into a `<script type="text/html">` tag and grab the innerHTML of that?

Comment: The problem is, how to get the exact data returned by PHP as a javascript string. Every method I tryed had been inconsistent between online and offline version of my website. That means it was unreliable.